# Cutting the Chalah diagonal slices

Tags: shabbat, minhag, challah-shabbat-bread

Is there a special reason why people cut the Chalah on Shabbos in diagonal slices

Comment: Because it’s easier for them to hold the knife that way? I’ve seen maybe one person do this, if by diagonal you mean not roughly perpendicular to the cutting board.

Comment: It's a way to cut pieces with a maximum volume and a minimum width. It's more easy to cut a great amount of slices manually. If there is a great number of mesubim who needs to eat from the bread on which the beracha was made.

Comment: I think its just that if follows the contours of a braided challa.

Comment: I think it reflects a religion based bias.